# Why are distant lights more flickery in peripheral vision?

Tags: visible-light, vision

I have just realized that if you arrange your angle to a flickering distant light source and make it fall into your far-peripheral vision (+70 degree to the side of your FOV), you perceive it to be flickering a lot faster.

**Details**

When I look at distant flickering street lights, I must pay special attention to tell that they are flickering. But when I change my angle and observe those with side of my field of vision, flicker rate is close to a TV screen with white noise, or a bubbles in heavily boiling water.

What is the reason of my peripheral vision capturing flickering of light better?

Comment: I think we've developed our eyes to be more alert wrt. movement in the periphery of our vision, to be able to detect attacking smilodons and the like. I don't remember my source, though.